# Converting String to java.net.URI

Tags: java, fedora-commons

First apologies, I'm mainly a Perl person doing some Java. I've read some literature but can't get this to give me the signature that I need:

```
    logger.debug("Entered addRelationships");
    boolean rval = true;
    for(int i=0;i<relationships.length;i++)
    {
        URI converted_uri ;
        try {
          converted_uri = new URI("relationships[i].datatype") ;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
          logger.error("Error converting datatype", e);
          return rval = false ;
        }

        boolean r = addRelationship(context, relationships[i].subject,
                relationships[i].predicate, relationships[i].object,
                relationships[i].isLiteral, converted_uri);
        if(r==false)
        {
            rval = false;
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```

The resulting error is:

`addRelationship(org.fcrepo.server.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String) in org.fcrepo.server.management.DefaultManagement cannot be applied to (org.fcrepo.server.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.net.URI)`

It seems to me that converted_uri **is a URI** at the end of this? datatype was a String in the previous release, so no gymnastics were required!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the qoutes:

```
converted_uri = new URI(relationships[i].datatype) ;
```

When you are using quotes, exactly as in perl you are dealing with string literal. If you want to refer to variable you have to mention it in code directly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't sure whether they worked in the same way.

Comment: All programming languages are the same... Well, except closure :)

Answer (score 1):

While @AlexR pointed out another problem in your code, it's not the cause of the problem you identified in your question.

You had a compile error, and an error in the syntax of the URI will only show up at runtime like the one that @AlexR identified.

The problem you have is that you are trying to pass a `URI` as the last argument, but the method `addRelationship` expects a `String` as the last argument. That's what the error says.

(The first part of the error says what the signature of the method is in reality, as you see it ends in `java.lang.String`, while the second part of the error says what type of data you are trying to give to the method, and as you see that one ends in `java.net.URI`)

So it seems that the URI was not changed as you expected; it still needs a String.

Solution is to change your code to:

```
boolean rval = true;
for(int i = 0; i < relationships.length; i++)
{
    boolean r = addRelationship(context, relationships[i].subject,
            relationships[i].predicate, relationships[i].object,
            relationships[i].isLiteral, relationships[i].datatype);
    if (!r)
    {
        rval = false;
    }
}
return rval;
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks my bad, I was 'reading' the error message the wrong way around, thought: `(org.fcrepo.server.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.net.URI)` was the method signature not the data. Something is wrong but I've got a successful compile using `String.valueOf(relationships[i].datatype)` for the moment. I can then take a closer look.